# Adding custom php file in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I want to add an additional php file, for example test.php in my wordpress theme, and access it with url like `example.com/wordpress/test.php`

When I place this test.php file in the theme directory, I can't access it.
So I how can I do that? It allows to access only if i place the test.php in the wordpress root, but i want to add the file in the theme directory instead of the root directory, which is at

```
wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme\test.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Avoid native php functions

1. They are not relative, so breaking stuff is easy. (like in the OPs case)
2. Why role your own if core got a function for you?
3. They don't consider edge cases

You should NEVER use the constants

- `STYLESHEET_DIRECTORY`
- `TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY`
- `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`
- etc...

<sup>Remember: Those are *not* API! and can therefore change!</sup>

*but* INSTEAD USE the following API functions:

- Parent Theme: `get_template_directory()` / `get_template_directory_uri()`
- Child Theme: `get_stylesheet_directory()` / `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

You can use both in Plugins

- `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/your/path/to/file.ext` <sup>*) for Themes also</sup>
- `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/your/path/to/file.ext`

but `plugin_dir_url()` is reserved only for Plugins.

### Keep in mind...

That there're

- Plugins
- MU-Plugins
- Drop-Ins
- Themes
- Themes in directories registered via `register_theme_directory( $dir );`

So please stick with the native API functions like `wp_upload_dir();`, `content_url();`, etc.

In general: Take a look at `/wp-includes/link-template.php` for a whole bunch of nice path and URl related API functions.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiser, working for me!  Child Theme: <?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/subfolder/file.php';?>